# Get values from the table and drop down list on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code that reads values from two columns (Members, Description) in the table dynamically on button click.

[Table html](https://jsfiddle.net/but98gfn/4/)

JQuery that reads the values from the table:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myButton').on('click', function() {

    var myCollection = [];

    $('div#body').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
      var row = this;
      var myObj = {


        label: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(1)').children())),
        opis: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(2)').children()))


      };
      myCollection[myCollection.length] = myObj;

    });

    console.log(myCollection)

    function valuefromType(control) {
      var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
      switch (type) {
        case "input":
          return $(control).val();
          break;
        case "span":
          return $(control).text();
          break;
        case "select":
          return $(control).val();
          break;
      }
    }

  });

});
```

On button click result stored in array is:

```
0: Object { label: "1", opis: null }
1: Object { label: "2", opis: "test2" }
​2: Object { label: "3", opis: "test3" }
3: Object { label: "5", opis: "3" }
4: Object { label: "9", opis: "test5" }
5: Object { label: "15", opis: "test88" }
```

Now I need to get the selected value (1,2,3,4,5 ...) from the dropdown list (House Center) that's located above the [table](https://jsfiddle.net/but98gfn/4/) and store it in the array on button click.

Can some one help me with that ?

Comment: `$('#MainContent_ddlBusinessCenter').val()` ?

Comment: Yes (1,2,3,4,5...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare array out of `click` event, and then add new event binded to your select like this:

```js
$('#MainContent_ddlBusinessCenter').on('change', function () {
    myCollection.push($(this).val());
});
```

If you want to stroe it the same way as are the previous values do it like this:

```js
$('#MainContent_ddlBusinessCenter').on('change', function () {
    var dropdown = $(this);
    myCollection.push({label: dropdown.val(), opis: dropdown.find("option:selected").text()});
});
```

**EDIT**

You can change this `myCollection[myCollection.length] = myObj;` to this `myCollection.push(myObj)`. It is less memory consuming.

And try to minimize the use of `$()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myButton').on('click', function() {

    var myCollection = [];

    $('div#body').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function(i, e) {
      var row = $(e);
      myCollection.push({
        label: valuefromType(row.find(row.find('td:eq(1)').children())),
        opis: valuefromType(row.find(row.find('td:eq(2)').children())),
        ddl: $('#MainContent_ddlBusinessCenter').val()
      });
    });

    console.log(myCollection);
  });

  function valuefromType(control) {
    var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
    switch (type) {
      case "input":
        return $(control).val();
      case "span":
        return $(control).text();
      case "select":
        return $(control).val();
    }
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/but98gfn/47/)

Comment: Hello Krzysztof, thanks for your response !
Did you mean like this ?

https://jsfiddle.net/but98gfn/36/

Comment: Unfortunately no with code I sent you result is the same.
Only two columns are shown in the array without the value of drop down :/

Comment: @freej17 take a look at edit. I guess this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This code works but I need it a little bit different.

Now resault of array is :

`0: Object { label: "1", opis: "" }
​
1: Object { label: "2", opis: "" }
​
2: Object { label: "3", opis: "" }
​
3: Object { label: "5", opis: "1" }
​
4: Object { label: "9", opis: "" }
​
5: Object { label: "15", opis: "" }
​
6: Object { label: "1", opis: "RR" }`

Where the ddl name is on the last place

Comment: And I need the value(1,2,3,4...)  in this case "2" of drop down (not the name RR....) to be in column number three like this:
`0: Object { label: "1", opis: "test1" , ddl: "2"}
​
1: Object { label: "2", opis: "test2" , ddl: "2" }
​
2: Object { label: "3", opis: "test4" , ddl: "2" }
​
3: Object { label: "5", opis: "test5" , ddl: "2"}
​
4: Object { label: "9", opis: "test6" , ddl: "2"}
​
5: Object { label: "15", opis: "test7", ddl: "2" }
​
6: Object { label: "1", opis: "testasd", ddl: "2" }
`


Hope this helps !!!

Comment: @freej17 No, actually I have absolutely no idea what you mean. What is `ddl`? And maybe now that you see how it works you can do it by your own. I'd wrte you what to do, but I don't know what you would like to achieve :)

Comment: Sorry my mistake :(

ddl is value of drop down list.
Drop down list in this case is House Center.
In this example from jsfiddle the second value is HE, and I need the value of 2 to populate whole third column in the array. I need value not the name :)
And if i chose value of three is HT and when selected I need the whole column number three to be populated with the value of 3.

I need this value in new column not the last row.

Hope this help ! :)
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Ok here you go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172981/discussion-between-freej17-and-krzysztof-janiszewski).

Comment: Sorry if I'm boring but I can't find any code in your last comment :/
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Like that : 
[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/but98gfn/28/)

JS:

```
$('#MainContent_ddlBusinessCenter').on('change', function () {
var value = $('#MainContent_ddlBusinessCenter').val();
alert(value);
});
```