# Read the values from table and drop down list on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code that reads values from two columns (Members, Description) in the table dynamically on button click.

[Table html](https://jsfiddle.net/but98gfn/4/)

JQuery that reads the values from the table:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myButton').on('click', function() {

    var myCollection = [];

    $('div#body').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
      var row = this;
      var myObj = {


        label: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(1)').children())),
        opis: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(2)').children()))


      };
      myCollection[myCollection.length] = myObj;

    });

    console.log(myCollection)

    function valuefromType(control) {
      var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
      switch (type) {
        case "input":
          return $(control).val();
          break;
        case "span":
          return $(control).text();
          break;
        case "select":
          return $(control).val();
          break;
      }
    }

  });

});
```

On button click result stored in array is:

```
0: Object { label: "1", opis: null }
1: Object { label: "2", opis: "test2" }
​2: Object { label: "3", opis: "test3" }
3: Object { label: "5", opis: "3" }
4: Object { label: "9", opis: "test5" }
5: Object { label: "15", opis: "test88" }
```

Now I need jquery to get the selected value (1,2,3,4,5 ...) from the dropdown list (House Center) that's located above the [table](https://jsfiddle.net/but98gfn/4/) and store it in the array in the third column on button click.

In my code when I click on the value from drop down the page refreshes and generetes a new table so it can's be .on('change', function ().

Can some one help me with that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get values from the table and drop down list on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814464/get-values-from-the-table-and-drop-down-list-on-button-click)

Comment: Check my edited answer in your previous question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you reply !
I'm testing now :)

Comment: I answered it on the topic before !